# How do you modify the following script to make the ninth word bold?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var toBold = document.getElementsByClassName('bold-second-word');
for (var i=0; i<toBold.length; ++i) {
  boldsecondWord(toBold[i]);
}

function boldsecondWord(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(/\w+ (\w+)/, function(s, c) {
    return s.replace(c, '<b class="bum">'+c+'</b>');
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="bold-second-word">John Smith is a great football player and deserves a medal for her achievments</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">This guy is not up to the task, so we have to fire him from his job.</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">Something is on my mind all day, but i do not want to share it with anyone.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">Today the weather is very cold and i would not like to get out of the bed, even if somebody paid me.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">This place is not what i was looking for my vacation. I will leave.</p>
</body>
```

I have been trying to modify it, but was not successful at it. Thank you

Comment: Or how do you modify the above that it makes the ninth word bold?

Answer (score 1):

The replace part is looking for the nine first words and captures two groups :
- the first eight words : `$1`
- the ninth word  : `$2`

```js
var toBold = document.getElementsByClassName('bold-second-word');
for (var i=0; i<toBold.length; ++i) {
  boldsecondWord(toBold[i]);
}

function boldsecondWord(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(/((?:[\w,]+ ){8})(\w+)/, '$1<b class="bum">$2</b>');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="bold-second-word">John Smith is a great football player and deserves a medal for her achievments</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">This guy is not up to the task, so we have to fire him from his job.</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">Something is on my mind all day, but i do not want to share it with anyone.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">Today the weather is very cold and i would not like to get out of the bed, even if somebody paid me.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">This place is not what i was looking for my vacation. I will leave.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why bother with capturing the initial eight words?

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's done in one replace instead of two. The replace will replace 9 words, so I need the nine words to keep the full sentence. Without capturing the initial 8 words, they would be missing in the result.

Comment: Yes, I was forgetting that lookbehinds are not yet ubiquitous.  They should make this sort of thing nicer.  Something like `.replace(/(?<=^(?\w+ ){8})(\w+)/, '<b>$1</b>')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function nineBold(elem){
   let str_arr = elem.innerHTML.split(' ');
   if(!str_arr[8]){ return false }
   str_arr[8]='<b class="bum">'+str_arr[8]+'</b>';
   elem.innerHTML = str_arr.join(' ');
 }
```

may be it help you, but best way is long

Answer (score 0):

If you want to somehow reuse the original regex:

```js
var toBold = document.getElementsByClassName('bold-second-word');
for (var i=0; i<toBold.length; ++i) {
  boldsecondWord(toBold[i]);
}

function boldsecondWord(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(/(?:\w+,? ){8}(\w+)/, function(match, p1) {
    return match.replace(p1, '<b class="bum">'+p1+'</b>');
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="bold-second-word">John Smith is a great football player and deserves a medal for her achievments</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">This guy is not up to the task, so we have to fire him from his job.</p>
  <p class="bold-second-word">Something is on my mind all day, but i do not want to share it with anyone.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">Today the weather is very cold and i would not like to get out of the bed, even if somebody paid me.</p>
   <p class="bold-second-word">This place is not what i was looking for my vacation. I will leave.</p>
</body>
```

The idea is to repeat the first group 8 times (with `{8}`) but not capture it
, by using non-capturing group `(?:`.

The problem on the third sentence is that, if it captures the 9th word, which is "i", and replace with `string.replace()` method. The method simply replaces the first `i` in the whole string so i bold the i character in "Somthing".

You might want to do some modification on the returning statement.